# AWS CannotPullContainerError no space left on device Docker

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, batch-file, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to use a large docker image (the image is on dockerhub [here](https://hub.docker.com/r/cornhundred/dockerized-cellranger-nick/) about 18GB) as a job definition for AWS batch. I'm getting the following error about running out of space:

`CannotPullContainerError: write /var/lib/docker/tmp/GetImageBlob#######: no space left on device`

The Cloudformation JSON section that defines the job is here

```
  "JobDef3": {
      "Type": "AWS::Batch::JobDefinition",
      "Properties": {
        "Type": "container",
        "ContainerProperties": {
          "Image": {
            "Fn::Join": [
              "",
              [
                "cornhundred/",
                "dockerized-cellranger-nick:latest"
              ]
            ]
          },
          "Vcpus": 1,
          "Command": ["some command"],
          "Memory": 3000,
        },
        "RetryStrategy": {
          "Attempts": 1
        }
      }
    },
```

How can I get AWS to increase the amount of space available so that I can run this image?

Comment: Sounds like something you should take up with AWS.  Are you a paying customer or using one of their free trials?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to run the docker container by moving the large files (~15GB reference genome files) out of the docker image and downloading them after running the container. I also needed to make a custom Amazon Machine Image (AMI, see [AWS Batch Genomics](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-high-throughput-genomic-batch-workflows-on-aws-batch-layer-part-3-of-4/) for an example) and attach a volume to handle the large reference genome files since the default container was not large enough.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue.   Clearing up unused docker images and volumes didn't work for me (ie `docker container prune` nor `docker system prune`

I saw another page saying that restarting docker fixed it for that user, but doing a `service docker restart` I got this error: **/etc/init.docker: line 35: ulimit: open files: cannot modify limit: Operation not permitted**

To try and fix that issue, I saw sites mentioning to update the ulimit values in some configuration files but when I tried to save the file with the updated parameters I got **write error (file system full?)**

At which point, I realized (as the initial error you showed) I needed to clean up and remove files.

I did a `du -h` from the root folder and saw that the `/var/lib/docker/tmp/` folder (which is part of the error message I experienced and  you posted above) used up way more disk space than other folders.

So I removed older files there and I no longer got that error message.